# Real world use of GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt

How do I make use of Generalized Algebraic Data Type?

The example given in the [haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) is too short to give me an insight of the real possibilities of GADT.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found the "Prompt" monad (from the "MonadPrompt" package) a very useful tool in several places (along with the equivalent "Program" monad from the "operational" package.  Combined with GADTs (which is how it was intended to be used), it allows you to make embedded languages very cheaply and very flexibly.  There was a pretty good article in the [Monad Reader issue 15](http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/issue15.pdf) called "Adventures in Three Monads" that had a good introduction to the Prompt monad along with some realistic GADTs.

Answer (score 53):

GADTs are weak approximations of inductive families from dependently typed languages—so let's begin there instead.

Inductive families are the core datatype introduction method in a dependently typed language. For instance, in Agda you define the natural numbers like this

```
data Nat : Set where
  zero : Nat
  succ : Nat -> Nat
```

which isn't very fancy, it's essentially just the same thing as the Haskell definition

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

and indeed in GADT syntax the Haskell form is even more similar

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Nat where
  Zero :: Nat
  Succ :: Nat -> Nat
```

So, at first blush you might think GADTs are just neat extra syntax. That's just the very tip of the iceberg though.

---

Agda has capacity to represent all kinds of types unfamiliar and strange to a Haskell programmer. A simple one is the type of finite sets. This *type* is written like `Fin 3` and represents the *set* of numbers `{0, 1, 2}`. Likewise, `Fin 5` represents the set of numbers `{0,1,2,3,4}`.

This should be quite bizarre at this point. First, we're referring to a type which has a regular number as a "type" parameter. Second, it's not clear what it means for `Fin n` to represent the set `{0,1...n}`. In real Agda we'd do something more powerful, but it suffices to say that we can define a `contains` function

```
contains : Nat -> Fin n -> Bool
contains i f = ?
```

Now this is strange again because the "natural" definition of `contains` would be something like `i < n`, but `n` is a value that only exists in the type `Fin n` and we shouldn't be able to cross that divide so easily. While it turns out that the definition is not nearly so straightforward, this is exactly the power that inductive families have in dependently typed languages—they introduce values that depend on their types and types that depend on their values.

---

We can examine what it is about `Fin` that gives it that property by looking at its definition.

```
data Fin : Nat -> Set where
  zerof : (n : Nat) -> Fin (succ n)
  succf : (n : Nat) -> (i : Fin n) -> Fin (succ n)
```

this takes a little work to understand, so as an example lets try constructing a value of the type `Fin 2`. There are a few ways to do this (in fact, we'll find that there are exactly 2)

```
zerof 1           : Fin 2
zerof 2           : Fin 3 -- nope!
zerof 0           : Fin 1 -- nope!
succf 1 (zerof 0) : Fin 2
```

This lets us see that there are two inhabitants and also demonstrates a little bit of how type computation happens. In particular, the `(n : Nat)` bit in the type of `zerof` reflects the actual *value* `n` up into the type allowing us to form `Fin (n+1)` for any `n : Nat`. After that we use repeated applications of `succf` to increment our `Fin` values up into the correct type family index (natural number that indexes the `Fin`).

What provides these abilities? In all honesty there are many differences in between a dependently typed inductive family and a regular Haskell ADT, but we can focus on the exact one that is most relevant to understanding GADTs.

In GADTs and inductive families you get an opportunity to specify the *exact* type of your constructors. This might be boring

```
data Nat where
  Zero :: Nat
  Succ :: Nat -> Nat
```

Or, if we have a more flexible, indexed type we can choose different, more interesting return types

```
data Typed t where
  TyInt  :: Int                -> Typed Int
  TyChar :: Char               -> Typed Char
  TyUnit ::                       Typed ()
  TyProd :: Typed a -> Typed b -> Typed (a, b)
  ...
```

In particular, we're abusing the ability to modify the return type based on the *particular* value constructor used. This allows us to reflect some value information up into the type and produce more finely specified (fibered) typed.

---

So what can we do with them? Well, with a little bit of elbow grease we can [produce `Fin` in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fin-0.1.0/docs/Data-Number-Fin-Integer.html). Succinctly it requires that we define a notion of naturals in types

```
data Z
data S a = S a

> undefined :: S (S (S Z))  -- 3
```

... then a GADT to reflect values up into those types...

```
data Nat where
  Zero :: Nat Z
  Succ :: Nat n -> Nat (S n)
```

... then we can use these to build `Fin` much like we did in Agda...

```
data Fin n where
  ZeroF :: Nat n -> Fin (S n)
  SuccF :: Nat n -> Fin n -> Fin (S n)
```

And finally we can construct exactly two values of `Fin (S (S Z))`

```
*Fin> :t ZeroF (Succ Zero)
ZeroF (Succ Zero) :: Fin (S (S Z))

*Fin> :t SuccF (Succ Zero) (ZeroF Zero)
SuccF (Succ Zero) (ZeroF Zero) :: Fin (S (S Z))
```

But notice that we've lost a lot of convenience over the inductive families. For instance, we can't use regular numeric literals in our types (though that's technically just a trick in Agda anyway), we need to create a separate "type nat" and "value nat" and use the GADT to link them together, and we'd also find, in time, that while type level mathematics is painful in Agda it can be done. In Haskell it's incredibly painful and often cannot.

For instance, it's possible to define a `weaken` notion in Agda's `Fin` type

```
weaken : (n <= m) -> Fin n -> Fin m
weaken = ...
```

where we provide a very interesting first value, a proof that `n <= m` which allows us to embed "a value less than `n`" into the set of "values less than `m`". We can do the same in Haskell, technically, but it requires heavy abuse of type class prolog.

---

So, GADTs are a resemblance of inductive families in dependently typed languages that are weaker and clumsier. Why do we want them in Haskell in the first place?

Basically because not all type invariants require the full power of inductive families to express and GADTs pick a particular compromise between expressiveness, implementability in Haskell, and type inference.

Some examples of useful GADTs expressions are [Red-Black Trees which cannot have the Red-Black  property invalidated](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ti5il/redblack_trees_in_haskell_using_gadts_existential/) or [simply-typed lambda calculus embedded as HOAS piggy-backing off the Haskell type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type#Higher-order_abstract_syntax).

In practice, you also often see GADTs use for their implicit existential context. For instance, the type

```
data Foo where
  Bar :: a -> Foo
```

implicitly hides the `a` type variable using existential quantification

```
> :t Bar 4 :: Foo
```

in a way that is sometimes convenient. If you look carefully the HOAS example from Wikipedia uses this for the `a` type parameter in the `App` constructor. To express that statement without GADTs would be a mess of existential contexts, but the GADT syntax makes it natural.

Comment: Why does ZeroF take a parameter n, since ZeroF is conceptually a constant? And why does ZeroF construct `Fin (S n))` instead of just `Fin n`, which seems more of a direct mapping? (Or why not even `Fin Z` ?)

Comment: It's a little strange, but the `Fin` type doesn't behave quite the same as the `Nat` type. Explicitly, for each `n` there is exactly one inhabitant of `Nat n` but `n` inhabitants of `Fin n`. Thus, `ZeroF` isn't actually a constant. The best I can say to learn more about how `Fin` works is to try to construct all of the elements of `Fin n` for various choices of `n`. It's rather counterintuitive, but makes sense with a little bit of practice.

Comment: @misterbee In Agda the `n` argument to the `Fin` constructors is often made implicit (`zerof : {n : Nat} -> Fin (suc n)`), which on the page makes `zerof` look a bit more like a constant and a `Fin` look a bit more like a number. `sucf (sucf zerof)` is the number 2 and can inhabit any `Fin n` for `n >= 3`.

Answer (score 25):

GADTs can give you stronger type enforced guarantees than regular ADTs. For example, you can force a binary tree to be balanced on the type system level, like in [this implementation](https://github.com/ppetr/haskell-typesafe-2-3-btrees/blob/master/BTree.hs) of [2-3 trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3_tree):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Zero
data Succ s = Succ s

data Node s a where
    Leaf2 :: a -> Node Zero a
    Leaf3 :: a -> a -> Node Zero a
    Node2 :: Node s a -> a -> Node s a -> Node (Succ s) a
    Node3 :: Node s a -> a -> Node s a -> a -> Node s a -> Node (Succ s) a
```

Each node has a type-encoded depth where all its leaves reside. A tree is then
either an empty tree, a singleton value, or a node of unspecified depth, again
using GADTs.

```
data BTree a where
    Root0 :: BTree a
    Root1 :: a -> BTree a
    RootN :: Node s a -> BTree a
```

The type system guarantees you that only balanced nodes can be constructed.
This means that when implementing operations like `insert` on such trees, your
code type-checks only if its result is always a balanced tree.

Comment: Not for anyone who studies this code before checking the definition of a 2-3 tree: Leaf2 and Node2 both have 1 data value; Leaf3 and Node3 both have 2 data vakues; Leaf2 and Leaf3 have no children  nodes; Node2 has 2 children and Node3 has 3 children. The numbers in the Leaf constructor names are slightly confusing.

Answer (score 4):

I like the example in [the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt).  It's a quick demo of a core GADT idea: that you can embed the type system of a language you're manipulating into Haskell's type system.  This lets your Haskell functions assume, and forces them to preserve, that the syntax trees correspond to well-typed programs.

When we define `Term`, it doesn't matter what types we choose.  We could write

```
data Term a where
  ...
  IsZero :: Term Char -> Term Char
```

or

```
  ...
  IsZero :: Term a -> Term b
```

and the definition of `Term` would still go through.

It's only once we want to *compute on* `Term`, such as in defining `eval`, that the types matter.  We need to have

```
  ...
  IsZero :: Term Int -> Term Bool
```

because we need our recursive call to `eval` to return an `Int`, and we want to in turn return a `Bool`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a short answer, but consult the Haskell Wikibook. It walks you though a GADT for a well-typed expression tree, which is a fairly canonical example: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT

GADTs are also used for implementing type equality: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-equality. I can't find the right paper to reference for this offhand -- this technique has made its way well into folklore by now. It is used quite well, however, in Oleg's typed tagless stuff. See, e.g. the section on typed compilation into GADTs. http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/#tc-GADT

Comment: It's basically 3 times the same example, and as I've told it in my question, it's not satisfactory.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I was redirecting you to the same link from your question -- for some reason I thought you were referring to the GHC docs. I don't see where you're coming from though. If you need a GADT, you'll probably know. And at that point, the wikibook summarizes pretty much how you would work with one. A more specific question would help.

Comment: Is [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/gadtoop.pdf) maybe the paper you were thinking of?